# Asp.net OpenID Identity Server specifying scope causes error

Tags: asp.net, openid, identityserver3

I have an ASP.Net web form site that I want to authenticate with Identity Server 3.  In the Identity Server app, I have a list of Scopes defined (one of which is "email").  But, when I run my code and attempt to authenticate, I get an error.  If I remove the Scope property, it runs fine, but does not include the Scope fields I requested (only has generic claims).  Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
                .AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            })

            Dim OpenIdAuthOption = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
               .Authority = "https://myidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/core/",
               .ClientId = "adfasdfafasdfasfasf",
               .RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44321/default.aspx/",
               .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
               .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
               .Scope = "email",
               .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                    .SecurityTokenReceived = Function(ctx)
                                                 Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                             End Function,
                    .MessageReceived = Function(ctx)
                                           Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                       End Function,
                    .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(ctx)
                                                  Dim claimPrincipal = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity
                                                  TransformClaims(claimPrincipal)
                                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                              End Function,
                    .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(ctx)
                                                     Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                 End Function,
                    .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(context)
                                                      RedirectLogin(context)
                                                      Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                  End Function
                    }
            }
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(OpenIdAuthOption)
        End Sub
```

The error  I get is:

> "OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error:
>   'invalid_request'. Error_Description (may be empty): ''. Error_Uri
>   (may be empty): ''."

can anyone explain how I can get the scope values (like "email) from Identity Server?

Comment: It could be that you are not allowed to request the email scope on that client.

Comment: The admin insists we have the scope available to the application.  And  I can see that its listed in the Discovery Document

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of your client configuration add openid as well it is mandatory scope to be there if you use response type (IdTokenToken/CodeIdToken/CodeToken/CodeIdTokenToken)

You code should be like

```
Dim OpenIdAuthOption = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
           .Authority = "https://myidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/core/",
           .ClientId = "adfasdfafasdfasfasf",
           .RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44321/default.aspx/",
           .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
           .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
           .Scope = "openid email",
           .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .SecurityTokenReceived = Function(ctx)
                                             Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                         End Function,
                .MessageReceived = Function(ctx)
                                       Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                   End Function,
                .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(ctx)
                                              Dim claimPrincipal = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity
                                              TransformClaims(claimPrincipal)
                                              Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                          End Function,
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(ctx)
                                                 Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                             End Function,
                .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(context)
                                                  RedirectLogin(context)
                                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                              End Function
                }
        }
```